# Webpack js not saving

Tags: javascript, caching, webpack

```
    var webpack = require('webpack');
    var path = require('path');
    let ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");
    var WebpackNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-notifier');
    var fs = require('file-system');
    var CleanWebpackPlugin = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
    var WebpackBuildNotifierPlugin = require('webpack-build-notifier');


    module.exports = {
    /*node: {
      fs: "empty"
    },*/
        resolve: {
        alias: {
          'masonry': 'masonry-layout',
          'isotope': 'isotope-layout'
        }
      },
        entry: './main.js',
        devtool: 'source-map',
        output: {
            path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/js'),
            filename: 'bundle.[chunkhash].js',
        },

        module: {
            rules: [
             {  test: /\.js$/, 
                    exclude: /node_modules/, 
                    loader: "babel-loader?presets[]=es2015",

                 },

                {
                    test:/\.scss$/,
                    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                        use: [{loader:'css-loader?sourceMap'}, {loader:'sass-loader', options: {
                        sourceMap: true,

                    }}],

                    })
                },   



                {
                     test: /\.vue$/,
            loader: 'vue-loader',
            options: {
              loaders: {
              }
              // other vue-loader options go here
            }
          },



            ]
        },  

        plugins: [

    new CleanWebpackPlugin(['js/*', 'css/*'], {
                root: '/Users/steve/sites/laravel/public',
                dry: false,
                watch: true,
        }),


     new WebpackBuildNotifierPlugin({
          title: "My Project Webpack Build",
          successSound: 'Blow',
          failureSound: 'Basso'
         // suppressSuccess: true
        }),

            //new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin(),
            new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/app.[chunkhash].css'),
            new WebpackNotifierPlugin({alwaysNotify: true}),

            function() {
                this.plugin('done', stats =>{
                    fs.writeFileSync(
                        path.join(__dirname, 'manifest.json'),
                        JSON.stringify(stats.toJson().assetsByChunkName)
                    )

                });
            }

        ]

};
```

Above is my webpack config file. It is supposed to delete both the .js and the app.css files using the CleanWebpackPlugin when either is saved and replace them with the new ones, appended with a cunkhash key.

This is an attempt at cache busting as it reads the manifest.json file.

If I save a .scss file the **app.0e2634cfba7a3ea1284e.css** is generated and the js is not.

The only way I can get it to replace both files is to actually write a line in the JS file and save.

Can anyone help me get the behaviour I need?

Comment: The only one difference which I've found between your config and the documentation is the way of specifying paths with wildcards, from the docs page: `'build/*.*',    // removes all files in 'build' folder` and you have `css/*` and `js/*` I know that it sounds silly, but I would try it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Oskar, will give it a try.